# Migration doesn't work when executed with cron

Tags: migrations

I've set up a migration between 2 Drupal sites hosted on the same server (Drupal 8 -> Drupal 9). I'm using [migration support recently added to drush](https://www.drush.org/latest/migrate/) to run these commands. I've created a helper bash script, which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
sites=(<mysite>)
for site in "${sites[@]}"; do
  drush -r /var/www/drupal -l $site mim <migration_id> --update --execute-dependencies >> /home/<myuser>/migration.log
done
```

This works fine, when I execute this script manually. However, it doesn't work (content isn't migrated), when it's executed by cron, defined like this:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /home/<myuser>/<myscript>.sh >> /home/<myuser>/migration.log
```

There's no output in the log and no errors in `/var/log/syslog`, where can I only see output like this every 5 minutes:

```
Feb 16 15:35:01 <hostname> CRON[22314]: (<myuser>) CMD (/home/<myuser>/<myscript>.sh >> /home/<myuser>/migration.log)
```

What can I do to debug this issue and resolve it?

Comment: This is not really a Drupal question. Asking how to set up, rund and debug cronjobs is better suited for StackOverflow

Comment: But the thing is that the cronjob itself apparently works, that's why I'm explicitly mentioning it at the end of my qustion. I believe it may be somehow related to the way drush works.

Comment: Drush does neither know nor care if it is run by a cronjob or manually. It is more likely your cronjob doesn't have the same environment as your manual shell (different user? different PHP version?...)

Comment: Thanks, I checked that I'm indeed running another script calling drush using the same user and the same shell (bash).

Comment: Cron doesn't source .bash_profile, which is often where the path to drush is included. As a dirty hack to test, add `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to the top of your user's `~/.profile` file, where `/usr/local/bin` is the path to the drush executable, and run cron (`~/.profile` is always sourced for cron in my experience)

Comment: As an aside, if you change the command to `/home/<myuser>/<myscript>.sh >> /home/<myuser>/migration.log 2>&1`, you should start seeing the log output

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I ended up using full path to drush. Also, this fix allowed my to see the log.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path to drush was wrong when the script was running by cron. Lesson learned - I should be using full paths when working with cron.